# jQuery ajax to get table from codebehind

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I get whole html table from coedebhind whitin jquery ajax as string and replace a div with it:
sample of creating table:

```
  resultTable = "<table id=\"result\">";
            resultTable += "<tr>";
......
```

and after creating whole table , pass it to client, and in ajax:

```
   $("#divresult").replaceWith(response.d);
```

anything was ok until i Needed to add hyperlink to a cell from codebehind :

```
value = "<a href=\"https://www.w3schools.com/html/\">Visit our HTML tutorial</a>";
```

after adding this i get Internal Server Error.

I changed dataType to text , html and json, but problem exists.
what can be the problem?

Comment: debug your service - something in it is throwing an exception.  As you have provided no c# code, it is impossible to say what causes it

Comment: try to encode the link using `encodeURI` and then decode in view

Comment: there is no error when   for example I set value="any simple thing" but when set for exampe <a></a> error happens

Comment: i used HttpUtility.UrlEncode it works with <a></a> but not with <a href=\"https://www.w3schools.com/html/\">Visit our HTML tutorial</a> also it renders encoded not as a link then

Comment: Could you try and use single qoute (') for enclosing the values of attributes instead of using escape sequence to accommodate double qoute(").

Comment: I have returned <a> tags many times with attribute values in single qoutes and return type JSON.